# Update Binding Dataset if User Deletes a Row from the DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I have a manually created a dataset (*dsPickingList*) that I add data too as the user inputs data on a form. There is a DataGridView on my form of which it's DataSource is set to *dsPickingList*.

What I would like to do is spot if a user deletes a row from the DataGridView and update the dataset (*dsPickingList*) as it is ultimatly this dataset that is stored to the db and printed, not the DataGridView.

The code I have at the moment is:

```vb
Private Sub DGV1_UserDeletedRow(sender As Object,
                                e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs) _
        Handles DGV1.UserDeletedRow

    If DGV1.RowCount = 0 Then
        Shortfall = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each row As DataRow In dsPickingList.Tables("ProductsRequired").Rows
        If row("ShortFall") < 0 Then
            Shortfall = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I need the action from the DataGridView to update the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is end the edit on the data grid view to end the editing which in turn updates the dataset.

`DGV1.EndEdit`

Paul.